# Se puede reutlizar el mismo RelativeLayout en Android Studio?

Tags: android-layout

Estoy iniciándome en esto de programación en Android Studio y quiero hacer una botonera que es toda igual, sólo cambia el sonido en cada *Layout*. Mi pregunta es: ¿hay alguna forma de guardar ese `RelativeLayout` para que se copie una cantidad de veces y que solo se cambie el sonido en cada botón *Play*? ¿O tengo que hacer para cada `RelativeLayout` la misma programacion? Como se ve en la imagen quiero hacer una lista de eso.

[image]

Eso es un `RelativeLayout` que quiero que se repita hacia abajo y que cambie solo el sonido al darle al bóton *Play*.

Comment: `ReciclerView`, `ListView`, etc, etc. Revisa la documentación de contenedores.

Comment: Gracias, ahora tengo otro problema pero trataré de solucionarlo antes de preguntar por acá, nuevamente gracias.